# Something Like Java WatchService to Monitor Incoming Email

Tags: email, monitoring, watchservice

I am wondering whether Java WatchService cab be extended to monitor incoming emails for an online order system.

I can do it by a timer I assume to periodically poll the inbox, but it seems too cumbersome and not nearly as neat as WatchServices. Or I can probably use a plugin in outlook to download a copy of the email to a folder to trigger a file watching WatchService. Or is there a better mechanism out there to achieve the same?

Any idea is welcome. Thanks/Jon

Comment: Just a little background: My goal is to send the new order in an incoming email to a USB POS printer right away. Java WatchService works very nicely when an order file is created in a monitored folder, which is perfect for in store orders since both the folder and printer are located within the store network. To monitor an inbox seems a different animal. Thanks/Jon

Comment: What is your goal, you say "monitor incoming emails", but do you want to be notified if the emails sit in a queue and are not processed by the printer?